# Select rows in one table that comes from a range of two columns in another table using R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I need to save the lines from "map" only when the rows are in the interval from the "ref" table:

Follow example to the "map" table:

```
map<-"chr start tag depth BCV State
chr1 1 chr1-1 1 2 1
chr1 2 chr1-2 1 3 2
chr1 3 chr1-3 1 2 3
chr1 4 chr1-4 2 2 4
chr2 5 chr2-5 2 2 5
chr2 1 chr2-1 2 2 6
chr2 2 chr2-2 3 2 4
chr2 3 chr2-3 3 2 3
chr2 4 chr2-4 3 2 2
chr2 5 chr2-5 3 2 1
chr2 6 chr2-6 3 2 7
chr2 7 chr2-7 3 2 9
chr2 8 chr2-8 2 2 2
chr2 9 chr2-9 2 2 1"
map<-read.table(text=map,header=T)
```

And I have a reference map like this example:

```
ref<-"chr start end
chr1 1 2 
chr1 2 3 
chr1 5 6 
chr2 7 9" 
ref<-read.table(text=ref,header=T)
```

And I need a final table like this:

```
final<-"chr start tag depth BCV State
chr1 1 chr1-1 1 2 1
chr1 2 chr1-2 1 3 2
chr1 3 chr1-3 1 2 3
chr2 7 chr2-7 3 2 9
chr2 8 chr2-8 2 2 2
chr2 9 chr2-9 2 2 1"
final<-read.table(text=final,header=T)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this was tagged with `data.table` tag, here's a simple `data.table::forverlaps` solution

```
setDT(map)[, end := start]
setkey(setDT(ref))
indx <- unique(foverlaps(map, ref, which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L)$xid)
map[indx]
#     chr start    tag depth BCV State end
# 1: chr1     1 chr1-1     1   2     1   1
# 2: chr1     2 chr1-2     1   3     2   2
# 3: chr1     3 chr1-3     1   2     3   3
# 4: chr2     7 chr2-7     3   2     9   7
# 5: chr2     8 chr2-8     2   2     2   8
# 6: chr2     9 chr2-9     2   2     1   9
```

This is basically adds an `end` column to `map` in order to close the intervals, `key` the `ref` data set in order to define the matching intervals for `foverlaps` while `chr` is also included. Then just running `foverlaps` while removing the unmatched values and selecting the `unique` overlaps in case the intervals in `ref` are overlapping. Finally just subsetting `map` according to the index.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to expand the intervals:

```
L <- lapply(split(ref,ref$chr), function(d) unique(unlist(mapply(seq,d$start,d$end,SIMPLIFY = F))))
```

which will give you:

```
#$chr1
#[1] 1 2 3 5 6

#$chr2
#[1] 7 8 9
```

And then you can merge:

```
ref2 <- setNames(stack(L),c('start','chr'))
merge(map,ref2)
```

Final output:

```
#   chr start    tag depth BCV State
#1 chr1     1 chr1-1     1   2     1
#2 chr1     2 chr1-2     1   3     2
#3 chr1     3 chr1-3     1   2     3
#4 chr2     7 chr2-7     3   2     9
#5 chr2     8 chr2-8     2   2     2
#6 chr2     9 chr2-9     2   2     1
```